# Java EE. Интерцептор и new

Tags: java-ee

Как известно, в *Java EE* есть интерцепторы. Интерцептор - это некоторый класс, перехватывающий вызовы методов целевого класса и "оборачивающий" их в некоторую дополнительную функциональность. Например, аннотация `@Transactional` "оборачивает" вызов перехватываемых методов в транзакцию.

Но интерцепторы работают только в том случае, когда целевой объект создан контейнером. Если объект создаётся при помощи `new`, интерцептор не применяется.

Что же делать в том случае, когда экземпляр класса производится фабрикой (аннотация `@Produces`), вызывающей `new`? Как "привязать" интерцепторы к объектам, созданным фабрикой при помощи оператора `new`?

Answer (score 3):

Я вижу использование интерсепторов в более глобальном смысле, то есть например при использовании уровня **DAO**, **Service**, **Controller**, при этом используется `Spring` с аннотациями `@Autowire`, каждый вызов при этом будет перехвачен соответствующим interceptorom например:

```
@Aspect
...
        @Around("execution(* com.mycompany.controller.*.*(..))")
        public Object interceptController(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
                try {
                  result = pjp.proceed();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                                       }
        return result

        }
```

Это полезно использовать для перехвата всех **Exception** для общего стиля их обработки. Но может использоваться любая другая логика например найти шпиона :).

В вашем же случае, если я правильно понял вы хотите обернуть выполнения метода какого то класса в `interceptor` при этом класс будет создан оператором `new`. В таком случае советую написать свой кастомный `interceptor`, уже даже есть паттерн программирования для этой цели. Называется `Proxy`.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/proxy_pattern.htm

В двух словах расскажу как вижу реализацию.
Есть общий интерфейс между объектом на котором будет вызываться метод и `interceptor` который будет перехватывать.

В интерсепторе будет ссылка на объект и он же будет вызывать метод на реальном объекте после того или до как будет выполнена соответствующая функц. логика в interceptore. Далее Вам остается только засетить реальный объект в `interceptor` и использовать его как реальный объект, это получится делать так как interface у них общий.

Comment: То, что Вы предлагаете - не интерцептор, а прокси. Интерцепторы в *Java EE* вызываются "прозрачно" и не имеют общих интерфейсов с "обёртываемым" объектом. У них есть метод, аннотированный `@AroundInvoke`, который и вызывается вместо любого "обёрнутого" им метода. Интерцептор не привязан к конкретному целевому классу/методу и может быть применён к (почти) любому классу/методу.

Comment: используйте AOP.